# How to Save a file as csv using the current file name

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macro that convers the date format of my data and then saves the file in a csv format (file format originally Excel). I need to run this macro on multiple files, so need the save name to change according to the current file name. I have the following code but it wont work:

```
Sub Conversion()
'
' Conversion Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+C
'
Dim OutputFile As String

    Columns("F:G").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Range("A1").Select
    ChDir "S:\BCC\MDT Teams\Yale\AXA\Orbit Implementation\TRS\DTO Access Exports"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "S:\BCC\MDT Teams\Yale\AXA\Orbit Implementation\TRS\DTO Access Exports\DTO_" + ActiveWorkbook.FullName + ".csv", _
         FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveWorkbook.FullName` includes the full path.
`ActiveWorkbook.Name` has just the filename

Note that both have the file extension still on there, so using `replace(activeworkbook.Name,".xlsm","")` *(alter extension to suit your needs)* should fix that issue